Can't reproduce Azure App Service SNAT ports exhaustion?
I've read this article (https://4lowtherabbit.github.io/blogs/2019/10/SNAT/#snat-ports-exhaustion) regarding the SNAT port exhaustion.
It mentions that:

TCP SNAT port release

If either server/client sends FINACK, SNAT port will be released after 240 seconds.
If a RST is seen, SNAT port will be released after 15 seconds.
If idle timeout has been reached, port is released.

That means if a web application opens a HTTP connection to call its
backend Restful web service once every second and well closes the
connection after each call, it will occupy 240 SNAT ports in 240
second.
That also means a busy website whose SQL database connection pool size
is 300, will occupy 300 SNAT ports, when its SQL queries execute
slowly in the database.

I decided to test it myself and deployed 2 Express.js apps on a free tier App Service SnatTest and SnatDelay.
SnatDelay app has a route that sends a response with 60s delay:
//SnatDelay
router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, 60000)
  })
  res.json({success: true})
})

SnatTest app has a route that that calls SnatDelay app's route described above:
//SnatTest
router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const respObj = await fetch(".../SnatDelay")
    const data = await respObj.json()

    await res.json(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})

Finally, I run a script in my local dev environment that calls SnatTest:
for (let i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
  fetch(".../snatTest")
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((result) => console.log(`${i} result: ${result}`))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(`${i} error:${err}`)
    })
}

To my surprise, after a 60-second delay everything resolved without any issues. No errors on SnatTest app side, where I expected to see SNAT port exhaustion.
According to the article, however, I was expecting to get some 4xx errors / timeouts, etc.
Am I misunderstanding something? Does anyone know why it worked without any issues?
